# Java Standalone Webcam App

Tags: java, installation, video-streaming, videochat

Quick question, I'm using JMyron to make a videochatting app in Java, but JMyron needs to be installed on my computer before I can use it in code. Does that mean anyone that I give a standalone to will also have to install JMyron on their computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you add it as a jar inside your own deployed application's jar?

Eclipse should handle this if you use JMyron as a declared librairy for your project.
It will generate a jar that bundles JMyron: 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_export

Comment: So you should consider non java install softwares like zerog, or a custom installer.